# Django: Is there any way to copy a form in the admin to a user-facing page?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-admin

https://github.com/mikejohnsonjr/django-powerdns-manager

^ I want to copy the form for adding and editing and deleting new zones.

It's a bit counter-intuitive. For example, importing any zone form (like NsRecordModelForm or ARecordModelForm) on a user-facing page will result in being able to add any record (with no styles), rather than a specific type of record. https://github.com/mikejohnsonjr/django-powerdns-manager/blob/master/src/powerdns_manager/admin.py

Here is the ugly (no styles) anyzone-ModelForm form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1tho.png

And here is the admin interface for performing CRUD operations on zones: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Hqh.png

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.